# Configure Informix database to make it accessibe via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, informix

I've created the Informix database as described in my previous question ([Create Informix database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164545/create-informix-database)).
Now I need to have JDBC access to it. How should I configure the Informix database server?

I can create a database, tables, and run any queries via `dbaccess` utility.

I've attempted to connect to it via JDBC with the following connection string (`test`database was created by `dbaccess`):

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:8202/test:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver;user=informix;password=1111;
```

The result is:
`Connection refused  java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)`

Ok, since `user=informix` and `password=1111` are local Linux user and password, it looks like I have to add a `user` properly.

So, I've changed in `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/onconfig` the string
from `USERMAPPING OFF`
to `USERMAPPING ADMIN`.

Then I connected to `test` database via `dbaccess` and create user according to [CREATE USER statement doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1821.htm):

```
CREATE USER mary WITH PASSWORD "joebar" PROPERTIES UID 44567 GROUP(1234)
```

Again, no success with it:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:8202/test:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver;user=mary;password=joebar;
```

The result is the same:
`Connection refused  java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)`

Furthermore, I can't use this user to connect via `dbaccess`.
Literally:

- `dbaccess`
- `DBACCESS >>` Connection
- `CONNECTION >>` Connect
- `SELECT DATABASE SERVER >>` myserver
- `USER NAME >>` [RETURN] (type nothing)
- `SELECT DATABASE >>` choose test@myserver

The result is: `Database selected.`

But if I'm trying to use created user:

- `dbaccess`
- `DBACCESS >>` Connection
- `CONNECTION >>` Connect
- `SELECT DATABASE SERVER >>` myserver
- `USER NAME >>` mary
- `PASSWORD >>` joebar
- `SELECT DATABASE >>` choose test@myserver

The result is:

```
   387: No connect permission.
   111: ISAM error:  no record found.
```

Comment: When you created the database, did you grant access to the users you're trying to connect as? You don't have to grant it explicitly to "informix". Depending on the mode of the database, you may need to 'GRANT CONNECT TO PUBLIC' (or to specific users rather than everyone — GRANT CONNECT TO mary). If you created a MODE ANSI database, this probably necessary. If you created a regular logged database, then you probably don't need to do it. Check who has access by running 'SELECT * FROM "informix".sysusers' to see who does have access. You can use RESOURCE or DBA instead of CONNECT if you want..

Comment: Connection refused would indicate that your database is not listening on port 8202 on localhost, because Java cannot even connect to that port.

Comment: "Connection refused" from java should lead to a SQL error -908, meaning JDBC cannot connect to the port. This is before JDBC would authenticate the user. Are you running the JDBC program from the same machine where the database engine resides? Firewalls and forgetting to change 'localhost' to the actual host name are common issues when ran from another machine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, 
`GRANT CONNECT TO PUBLIC` -> 
`Permission granted.`

`GRANT CONNECT TO mary` -> 
`Permission granted.`

`SELECT * FROM "informix".sysusers` -> 
`Informix, mary, public` (can't format output as-is).

But the result is the same:
`jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:8202/test:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver;user=mary;password=joebar;`
-> `(Connection refused)  java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
`cat $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts` -> `myserver onsoctcp localhost port_alias`.
`cat /etc/services` -> `... port_alias 8202/tcp`.
`netstat -tulpn | grep 8202` -> `tcp6       0      0 ::1:8202                :::*                    LISTEN`

Comment: @BrianHughes Both Informix database and JVM running on localhost.

Comment: Are you sure the informix JDBC drivers supports IPv6? have you tried using the IPv6 address instead of localhost. With the current error, your question is technically a duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: I think if you are listening on an IPV6 port you need to check if localhost maps to it.  Or use ::1 as the host instead of 'localhost'.  My guess is the server is listening on the IPv6 network interface and not on the IPV4 localhost.

Comment: @BrianHughes, thank you! Using ::1 instead of localhost is a  solution.